# Filter and manipulate a map

Tags: flutter, dart

It's the first time I use Dart and I'm stuck with a simple thing.

I have a simple `Map` and I need to remove some items from this map and modify the content.

I have this:

```dart
  Map<String, List<String>> dataset = {
    'apple': ['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3'],
    'pear': ['pear1', 'pear2'],
    'ananas': ['ananas1', 'ananas2', 'ananas3'],
    'orange': ['orange1', 'orange2', 'orange3', 'orange4'],
  };
  List<Map<dynamic, String>> fruits = [
    {'key': 'pear', 'labelToShow': 'Pear fruit'},
    {'key': 'ananas', 'labelToShow': 'My ananas'},
  ];
```

and I would like to have this:

```dart
  Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = {
    'pear': {
      'values': ['pear1', 'pear2'],
      'labelToShow': 'Pear fruit'
    },
    'ananas': {
      'values': ['ananas1', 'ananas2', 'ananas3'],
      'labelToShow': 'My ananas'
    },
  };
```

So, basically, I need to remove from `dataset` the items that have the key that it's not included in `fruits` (in field `key`) and then I need to add the field `labelToShow`.

I dont' know ho to do that.

I started removing items from dataset doing so:

```dart
dataset.removeWhere((k, v) => k != 'pear' && k != 'ananas');
```

but I don't like, I would like to loop through `fruits`.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't remove anything from `dataset`. Instead I'd build a new map from scratch, with just the data you want.

How about:

```dart
  Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> result = {
    for (var fruit in fruits)
      fruit["key"]: {
        "values": dataset[fruit["key"]],
        "labelToShow": fruit["labelToShow"]
      }
  };
```